# Why are there black regions on sentinel data?

Tags: sentinel-2, copernicus

I'm a novice. I'm querying https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus with the following:

```
footprint:"Intersects(POLYGON((-49.6205 -22.0966,-49.6222 -22.1122,-49.6028 -22.1079,-49.5845 -22.1123,-49.5865 -22.1244,-49.5678 -22.1394,-49.5620 -22.1381,-49.5559 -22.1293,-49.5553 -22.1364,-49.5617 -22.1448,-49.5508 -22.1503,-49.5239 -22.1532,-49.5297 -22.1722,-49.5290 -22.1812,-49.5442 -22.1946,-49.5550 -22.2206,-49.5845 -22.2362,-49.5893 -22.2351,-49.5894 -22.2352,-49.5910 -22.2363,-49.6149 -22.2518,-49.6520 -22.2675,-49.6575 -22.2737,-49.6478 -22.2858,-49.6466 -22.2949,-49.6320 -22.3060,-49.6319 -22.3103,-49.6320 -22.3304,-49.6408 -22.3403,-49.6505 -22.3691,-49.6688 -22.3739,-49.6897 -22.3716,-49.7096 -22.3791,-49.7211 -22.3823,-49.7285 -22.3761,-49.7350 -22.3818,-49.7417 -22.3807,-49.7490 -22.3758,-49.7481 -22.3514,-49.7524 -22.3529,-49.7692 -22.3553,-49.7893 -22.3512,-49.8101 -22.3550,-49.8182 -22.3597,-49.8315 -22.3600,-49.8399 -22.3547,-49.8545 -22.3572,-49.8544 -22.3462,-49.8436 -22.3295,-49.8445 -22.3222,-49.8369 -22.3189,-49.8340 -22.3137,-49.8188 -22.3048,-49.8075 -22.3095,-49.8030 -22.3066,-49.8008 -22.2979,-49.7829 -22.2940,-49.7592 -22.2981,-49.7502 -22.2924,-49.7415 -22.2913,-49.7488 -22.2800,-49.7532 -22.2555,-49.7573 -22.2517,-49.7486 -22.2478,-49.7482 -22.2150,-49.7497 -22.2016,-49.7609 -22.1870,-49.7728 -22.1789,-49.7957 -22.1760,-49.8032 -22.1695,-49.8117 -22.1416,-49.8183 -22.1340,-49.8218 -22.1268,-49.8195 -22.1181,-49.8243 -22.1120,-49.8129 -22.1069,-49.8059 -22.1116,-49.8009 -22.1074,-49.7879 -22.1107,-49.7831 -22.1081,-49.7749 -22.1120,-49.7609 -22.1099,-49.7518 -22.1167,-49.7357 -22.1197,-49.7171 -22.1315,-49.7120 -22.1392,-49.7063 -22.1397,-49.6679 -22.1345,-49.6758 -22.1188,-49.6707 -22.1216,-49.6554 -22.1264,-49.6460 -22.1231,-49.6447 -22.1157,-49.6489 -22.1083,-49.6430 -22.0886,-49.6332 -22.0755,-49.6205 -22.0966)))"
```

Notice the sentinel 2 results come with *varying* levels of blacked out regions, which I assume are NODATA. Why is this? How can I test for this *before* downloading the product?

Edit: Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc5em.jpg

Notice the black regions on the results panel.

Comment: Speaking of not wanting to download the product, can you add some screenshots to your question so people can see what the results look like without having to download the query results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are merely outside of the captured area. The scene (captured area) is a parallelogram but the raster is a square. No different than landsat or ASTER or SPOT>.

Comment: Thanks, this had not crossed my mind at all.

I want squares without these black regions. What are my options? Mosaic adjacent granules and then crop a square?

Comment: you got it, if your AOI is not contained in a single scene this is the approach.